# Scrape Javascript page with Python or other

Tags: python, jquery, underscore.js, scrape

I want to scrape the team grids for each game on the following website:

http://mc.championdata.com/nrl/

and I believe the code below is for away teams:

```
<div class="cd6364_component cd6364_div_away_team_single" style="width: 100%;
```

How can I scrape this site?

Comment: What's your question? Are you working in python or javascript? What does this have to do with jquery and underscore?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner but I think I got what you are asking for. You could do it in python using BeautifulSoup and Requests. Something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

quote_page = "http://mc.championdata.com/nrl"
page = urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
name_box = soup.find("") 

#for example: soup.find("a", {"class": "price", "data-usd": True})['data-usd']
```

I don't understand what you are looking for exactly though.